# Sharing image on Instagram iOS, sometimes gets the last image from the gallery and not the downloaded image

Tags: file, xamarin.forms, download, xamarin.ios, storage

I'm using this code to download the image of an uri and then pass it to the function that opens Instagram like a UImage.The problem comes when I try to share another image, the application gets me the last image that I use, and not the one that I'm downloading or selecting, and I trying to delete this local file, but I can't remove it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/577839/sharing-image-on-instagram-ios-something-get-the-l.html

Comment: Do you check if the `imageName ` are same or not ? If you use the same name , it may use the original one .

Comment: Try to set `imageName ` as `new Random().Next(int.MaxValue).ToString()` .